# Animation of "moving the view out of the screen"

Tags: android, animation

I have a view in one RelativeLayout which acts as the title bar of an Activity.

When I scroll the list below it, I'd like the title bar to hide in a way that seems to be scrolled (or moved) out of the screen. This is quite simple and clear. I have tried two options but neither of them worked for me:

1. Use default layout animation. set the `animateLayoutChanges=true` for the parent ViewGroup and remove the title bar when needed. The effect I got is fade out the text on the title and the bar disappeared. this is not what I want, for I don't want the fade of the text.
2. use below code but what I got is a grey blank appeared after the title moved out. which is ugly.

   ```
   Animator disappearingAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(null, "translationY", 0, -(titleLin.getHeight()));
   LayoutTransition transition = new LayoutTransition();
   transition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, disappearingAnimation);
   transition.setDuration(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, 600);

   titleParent = (ViewGroup) titleLin.getParent();
   titleParent.setLayoutTransition(transition);
   titleLin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   ```

Is there any solution for this simple animation effect?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, in fact it is explained in the official reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html

the problem is caused by the default behavior of layout transition: first animate the removal of the view and then animate the filling of the rest.

so just set the delay time to zero for the animation will solve it.

Comment: in fact ,this is still not my best choice. what I really want is disappear the view just like the view is moved out of the screen. but the current effect is like the below view covered the view. And I wonder if I could do that if I keep current layout xml unchanged